# force component to rebuild on route change or vuex state change

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I want to get into VueJs / Vuex and created a small todo app. There are three links for "all todos", "pending ones" and "completed ones". It's the same route but with a different `filter` query.

When changing the route the component will not update, because it seems that updated query is not forcing an component update. But the `computed` event gets triggered.

I created a small example showing my current problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/6zx2p0m20r

If you click around on the todo links there will be no component update. If you head over to "another route" and head back, the component was updated (because of a completely different route).

How can I force to update the component on a query update within the same base route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `beforeRouteUpdate` navigation guard to reinitialize your data:

> `beforeRouteUpdate` is called when the route that renders this component has changed,
>   but this component is reused in the new route.
>
> For example, for a route with dynamic params `/foo/:id`, when we
>   navigate between `/foo/1` and `/foo/2`, the same `Foo` component instance
>   will be reused, and this hook will be called when that happens.
>
> ([source](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards))

---

```js
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
  this.currentTodoFilter = to.query.filter
  next()
}
```

You can also remove your `updateTodoFilter` method this way.

Comment: thank you for your help but this didn't work for me. I updated the snippet https://codesandbox.io/s/oozn14x9oy?fontsize=14 maybe I did something wrong? I removed the `updateTodoFilter` function and added the `beforeRouteUpdate` to the router item

Comment: @Question3r It's an "in-component" guard. Just remove it from your router.js and add it in your Todos component. Here's the fixed codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/xo5j96xqo4

Comment: ah sorry, that worked! so when I want to update my URL I have to call the next function too right? Doing so works, just want to ask :)

Comment: sure but don't forget to add all the guard's arguments: `beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) { ...do something here... next() }`. I updated my answer.